# `overflow:auto` doesn't hide scrollbar in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following CSS:

```
  .show_dropdown {
    max-height: 350px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
```

in a mobile view the dropdown list is less than `350px` and this should hide scrollbar because it is not necessary. However, in bigger screen it works fine and hide scroll when it is not needed.

[image]

Thanks for reading and helping

Full code can be find [here](https://codepen.io/basirpayenda/pen/WNvweGM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `padding: 1.25rem 0;` in `nav > .navbar_list > a`  if you inspect and check, if destop view `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`  for each `a` tag is 43px whereas in mobile view it's 56px which increasing the overall height of the list and resulting the scrollbar visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vendor prefixes for this, and it's the approach I'd recommend.

```
.dropdown_list {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
.dropdown_list::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/CewisLewis/pen/poJyzJV

Comment: I appreciate your help I can scroll but it doesn't display the scrollbar.

I want it to display scrollbar when dropdown list is more than `350px` and hide it when it is less than `350px`